# How to disable graphics, consoles etc during kernel initialization?

Tags: kernel, display

My kernel (4.14-amd64) is currently flickering a lot during stage while I simply have a flashing cursor. It is cosmetically annoying, and I would like to disable the graphics from starting until the `initramfs` is loaded and my proper Intel graphics driver loads.

Basically, I want to pause the initialization of the screen until the `initramfs` loads my `plymouthd`, or maybe later.

I've read so much info about this, I can't link it all.

**EDIT1:** I don't mind if the `grub2` screen stays frozen during this stage.

**EDIT2:** I have Debian 9 Stretch with a backports kernel.

**EDIT3:** This is my first question on this community. Feel free to correct me if this is a bad question, etc.

**EDIT4:** My computer is Acer R3-131T with Intel Integrated Graphics.

Comment: You did not  specify on what hardware you have this problem. Also, did you try with other kernel versions?

Comment: I am using an Acer R3-131T with Intel Integrated Graphics. I tried other kernels but my guess is that I need to compile a kernel without framebuffer support..?

Answer (score 1):

You could try `nomodeset` as kernel boot parameter. This does not prevent output but prevents tge kernel from switching graphics card modes.

Comment: I have tried this; it worked (mostly) until plymouth actually loaded, but when it did, the top left block of the animation was black with a console cursor.

Comment: The thing is, having `nomodeset` won't prevent a service or software from loading FB-module as boot process progresses. It simply prevents Linux kernel from changing modes at boot time.

Answer (score 0):

`i915.modeset=0` along with `nouveau.modeset=0` should work for Intel drivers. A good write up on the available configuration options for Intel GFX chipsets can be found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics)

Comment: This answer is similar to the answer above; they both do the same thing on my laptop. Neither do what I want!

Comment: Yes, have you tried to do both? And perhaps add in a `nouveau.modeset=0`?

Comment: I tried both. I have no nouveau/nvidea chips at all

Comment: Did you read the link provided? I hate asking but this bit seems like it might be needed https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_mode_setting#Early_KMS_start

Comment: I'm on debian so there is no mkinitcpio, but I have read through the page from your comment page already, and nothing suggested there helps. The page in the answer doesn't seem to suggest any method to disable the console cursor or to remove flicker from KMS.